# I get a stackOverflowError when trying to generate a very large PDF file in Java

Tags: java, hibernate

**When the data to generate the PDF is small the PDF is generated without problems, but when the data is large I get stackOverflowError.**

```
16:40:37,510 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.LoadContexts] (default task-54) HHH000100: Fail-safe cleanup (collections) : org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext@5df3d7ab<rs=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl@357156df>
16:40:37,510 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext] (default task-54) HHH000160: On CollectionLoadContext#cleanup, localLoadingCollectionKeys contained [1] entries
16:40:37,528 ERROR [br.gov.ans.commons.rest.exception.handler.ExceptionHandler] (default task-54) org.modelmapper.MappingException: ModelMapper mapping errors:

1) Error mapping br.gov.ans.rps.rede.services.entities.Movimentacao to br.gov.ans.rps.rede.services.dtos.MovimentacaoDTO

1 error: org.modelmapper.MappingException: ModelMapper mapping errors:

1) Error mapping br.gov.ans.rps.rede.services.entities.Movimentacao to br.gov.ans.rps.rede.services.dtos.MovimentacaoDTO

1 error
    at org.modelmapper.internal.Errors.throwMappingExceptionIfErrorsExist(Errors.java:374)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.MappingEngineImpl.map(MappingEngineImpl.java:69)
    at org.modelmapper.ModelMapper.mapInternal(ModelMapper.java:497)
    at org.modelmapper.ModelMapper.map(ModelMapper.java:340)
    at br.gov.ans.rps.rede.services.business.SolicitacaoNegocio.converterMovimentacaoVO(SolicitacaoNegocio.java:394)
```

io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:264)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:175)
at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:207)
at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:802)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.jboss.logmanager.formatters.Formatters$14.renderRaw(Formatters.java:638)

**solicitacaoBean**

```
public StreamedContent imprimirSolicitacao(SolicitacaoVO solicitacaoVO){
        
        StreamedContent download = new DefaultStreamedContent();

        try {
            SolicitacaoVO solicitacaoCompleta = solicitacaoClient.buscarSolicitacao(solicitacaoVO.getId().toString(), true);
                        
            ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
            
            SolicitacaoVO solicitacaoImprimir = modelMapper.map(solicitacaoCompleta, SolicitacaoVO.class);
            
            for(MovimentacaoVO mov:solicitacaoImprimir.getListaMovimentacao()){
                
                List<PlanoVO> planosSemDuplicados = new ArrayList<PlanoVO>();
                mov.setListaPrestadoresExclusao(new ArrayList<PrestadorVO>());
                for (PlanoVO planoVO : mov.getListaPlanos()) {
                    if(!planosSemDuplicados.contains(planoVO)){
                        planosSemDuplicados.add(planoVO);
                    }
                    if(!mov.getListaPrestadoresExclusao().contains(planoVO.getPrestador())){
                        mov.getListaPrestadoresExclusao().add(planoVO.getPrestador());                              
                    }
                }
                mov.setListaPlanos(planosSemDuplicados);
                
                if ( mov.getReconsideracao()!=null && !mov.getReconsideracao().getArquivos().isEmpty() ){
                    
                    int sizeList = mov.getReconsideracao().getArquivos().size();
                    int i = 1;
                    StringBuffer aux = new StringBuffer();
                    for ( ArquivoReconsideracaoVO arq : mov.getReconsideracao().getArquivos() ){
                        aux.append(arq.getNomeArquivo());
                        if ( i < sizeList ){
                            aux.append(";  ");
                        }else {
                            aux.append(".");
                        }
                        i++;
                    }
                    mov.getReconsideracao().setNomeArquivosConcatenados(aux.toString());
                }
                
                Collections.sort(mov.getListaPrestadoresExclusao());
                Collections.sort(mov.getListaPrestadores());
            }
            
            InputStream pdfGerado = gerarRelatorioSolicitacaoOuMovimentacao(solicitacaoImprimir);
            download = prepararDownload(pdfGerado, "Solicitação", TipoArquivo.PDF.getContentType());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            exibirMensagemErro("erro.imprimir.pdf");
            logger.error(e,e);
            return null;
        }
        return download;
    }
```

**solicitacaoClient**

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class SolicitacaoClient implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Inject
    @PropertiesInfo(file="services.properties", key="rps.rede.services.rest.uri")
    @Server
    private String uri;
    
    @Inject
    @Autenticado(value = "rps.rede", type = AuthType.BEARER)
    private Client cliente;
        
    @Inject
    Logger logger;
    
    public List<OperadoraVO> consultarOperadoras(String filtroCodigo, String filtroCNPJ, String filtroNome) throws Exception{
        Response response = cliente.target(uri + "operadoras")
                .queryParam("codigo", filtroCodigo)
                .queryParam("cnpj", filtroCNPJ)
                .queryParam("nome", filtroNome)
                .request().get();
        try {
                if(response.getStatusInfo().getFamily() != Family.SUCCESSFUL){
                        throw new Exception(response.readEntity(ErrorMessage.class).getError());
                    } else{
                        String json = (String) response.readEntity(String.class);
                        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"));
                        List<OperadoraVO> operadoras = mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<List<OperadoraVO>>() { });
                        
                        return operadoras;
                    }
        } finally {
            response.close();
        }

    }
    
    public SolicitacaoVO buscarSolicitacao(String id, boolean lgCompleto) throws Exception{
        WebTarget target = cliente.target(uri + "/solicitacoes/" + id);
        
        target = target.queryParam("lg-completa", lgCompleto ? 1 : 0);
        
        Response response = target.request().get();
        
        try {
            if(response.getStatusInfo().getFamily() != Family.SUCCESSFUL){
                throw new Exception(response.readEntity(ErrorMessage.class).getError());
            } else{
                String json = (String) response.readEntity(String.class);
                ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"));
                return mapper.readValue(json, SolicitacaoVO.class);
            }
        } finally {
            response.close();
        }
    }
    
    public List<SolicitacaoVO> buscarSolicitacoes(String coOperadora, FiltroSolicitacao filtro) throws Exception{
        
        Response response = cliente.target(uri + "operadoras/" + coOperadora + "/solicitacoes")
            .queryParam("cdSituacao", filtro.getStatus())
            .queryParam("dataEnvioInicio", Utils.dateToString(filtro.getDataInicio(), "dd/MM/yyyy"))
            .queryParam("dataEnvioFim", Utils.dateToString(filtro.getDataFim(), "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"))
            .queryParam("protocolo", Utils.getSomenteNumeros(filtro.getProtocolo()))
            .queryParam("gru", filtro.getGru())
            .request().get();

        try {
            if(response.getStatusInfo().getFamily() != Family.SUCCESSFUL){
                throw new Exception(response.readEntity(ErrorMessage.class).getError());
            } else{
                String json = (String) response.readEntity(String.class);
                ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"));
                return mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<List<SolicitacaoVO>>() { });
            }
        } finally {
            response.close();
        }
    }
    
    public ComprovanteRelatorio montarComprovanteRelatorio(Integer idSolicitacao) throws Exception{
        
        Response response = cliente.target(uri + "/solicitacoes/" + idSolicitacao + "/montarComprovanteRelatorio").request().get();
        
        try {
            if(response.getStatusInfo().getFamily() != Family.SUCCESSFUL){
                throw new Exception(response.readEntity(ErrorMessage.class).getError());
            } else{
                String json = (String) response.readEntity(String.class);
                ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"));
                return mapper.readValue(json, ComprovanteRelatorio.class);
            }           
        } finally {
            response.close();
        }
    }

    public List<MovimentacaoRelatorioVO> montarRelatorioMovimentacoes(Integer idSolicitacao) throws Exception {
        
        Response response = cliente.target(uri + "/solicitacoes/" + idSolicitacao + "/relatorioMovimentacoes").request().get();

        gerarLogResponse(uri + "/solicitacoes/" + idSolicitacao + "/relatorioMovimentacoes", response);

        try {
            if(response.getStatusInfo().getFamily() != Family.SUCCESSFUL){
                throw new Exception(response.readEntity(ErrorMessage.class).getError());
            } else{
                String json = (String) response.readEntity(String.class);
                ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"));
                return mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<List<MovimentacaoRelatorioVO>>() { });
            }
        } finally {
            response.close();
        }
    }

    public List<MovimentacaoRelatorioVO> montarRelatorioConsultaMovimentacoesInterno(List<MovimentacaoVO> listaMovimentacoes) throws Exception {
        
        ConsultaMovimentacaoRelatorioVO consultaMovimentacaoRelatorioVO = new ConsultaMovimentacaoRelatorioVO();
        consultaMovimentacaoRelatorioVO.setListaMovimentacao(listaMovimentacoes);
        
        Response response = cliente.target(uri + "/solicitacoes/movimentacoes/relatorio/interno")
                .request().post(Entity.entity(consultaMovimentacaoRelatorioVO, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
        
        try {
            if(response.getStatusInfo().getFamily() != Family.SUCCESSFUL){
                throw new Exception(response.readEntity(ErrorMessage.class).getError());
            } else{
                String json = (String) response.readEntity(String.class);
                ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"));
                return mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<List<MovimentacaoRelatorioVO>>() { });
            }           
        } finally {
            response.close();
        }
    }
    
    private void gerarLogResponse(String url, Response response) {
        logger.info("URL chamada: " + url);
        logger.info("Header da resposta:");
        
        for (Entry<String, List<Object>> iterable_element : response.getHeaders().entrySet()) {
            for (Object iterable : iterable_element.getValue()) {
                logger.info(iterable_element.getKey() + " - " + iterable.toString());               
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**PDF Generator JasperReport**

```
public class ReportHelper {
    
    @Inject
    private static Logger LOGGER;

    public enum FORMATO_RELATORIO {
        XLS, PDF;
    }

    private static String gerarIdReport() {
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyyhhmmss");
        String id = simpleDateFormat.format(new Date());

        return id;
    }

    /**
     * Retorna caminho onde os relatórios (.jasper e .jrxml e tmps) ficam
     * armazenados
     * */
    private static String reportSourcePath() {

        return FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRealPath("/jasper/") + "/";
    }

    /**
     * Retorna o caminho onde os relatórios finais ficam no servidor (ex: .PDF)
     * */
    private String reportFile() {
        return FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getInitParameter("reportDirectory");
    }

    /**
     * Abrir Janela com Arquivo (PDF, XLS, TXT e etc)
     * */
    public void abrirPoupUp(String fileName) {
        abrirPoupUp(fileName, null);
    }

    public void abrirPoupUp(String fileName, String nomeJanela){
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
        String contextPath = req.getContextPath().replace("/", "");
        if (nomeJanela == null){
            nomeJanela = "Relatório";
        }

        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute(
            "window.open(/" + contextPath + "/jasper/" + fileName + ",'"+nomeJanela+"','width=800px,height=800px')");
        }

    /**
     * Gera o relatório e retorna o nome do relatório gerado
     * */
    private static InputStream gerarRelatorio(String relatorio, List<Object> beans, Map<String, Object> params, FORMATO_RELATORIO formatoExportacao) {
        try {
            if (params == null) {
                params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            }

            JRBeanCollectionDataSource beanCollectionDataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(beans);
            
            DefaultJasperReportsContext.getInstance().setProperty("net.sf.jasperreports.components.sort.up.arrow.char", "");
            DefaultJasperReportsContext.getInstance().setProperty("net.sf.jasperreports.components.sort.down.arrow.char", "");

            String relatorioFormated = relatorio.endsWith(".jasper") ? relatorio : (new StringBuilder()).append(relatorio).append(".jasper").toString();
            net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint jasperPrint = null;
            
            
            if (beans != null && beans.size() > 0) {
                jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reportSourcePath() + relatorioFormated, params, beanCollectionDataSource);
            } else {
                jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reportSourcePath() + relatorioFormated, params, new JREmptyDataSource());
            }

            StringBuilder nomeRelatorio = new StringBuilder();
            nomeRelatorio.append(relatorio + "_" + gerarIdReport());

            /*
             * JRExporter foi descontinuada. Utilizando JRPdfExporter e JRXlsExporter para tratar PDF e XLS separadamente.
             * -- Ricardo --
             */
            //JRExporter exporter = null;
            JRPdfExporter exporter_pdf = null;
            JRXlsExporter exporter_xls = null;

            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        
            if (formatoExportacao.equals(FORMATO_RELATORIO.PDF)) {
                exporter_pdf = new JRPdfExporter();
                nomeRelatorio.append(".pdf");
                
                exporter_pdf.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));
                exporter_pdf.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(stream));
                exporter_pdf.exportReport();
            }
                
            if (formatoExportacao.equals(FORMATO_RELATORIO.XLS)) {
                exporter_xls = new JRXlsExporter();
                nomeRelatorio.append(".xls");
                
                exporter_xls.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));
                exporter_xls.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(stream));
                exporter_xls.exportReport();
            }

            //ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            //exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
            //exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, stream);
            //exporter.exportReport();          

            return new ByteArrayInputStream(stream.toByteArray());
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error(e, e);
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Geração de Relatório em XLS
     */
    public static InputStream gerarRelatorioXLS(String relatorio, List<Object> beans, Map<String, Object> params) {

        return gerarRelatorio(relatorio, beans, params, FORMATO_RELATORIO.XLS);

    }

    /**
     * Padrão para Arquivos PDF
     * @throws FileNotFoundException 
     * */
    public static InputStream gerarRelatorioPDF(String relatorio, Object object) throws FileNotFoundException {
        List<Object> beans = new ArrayList<Object>();
        beans.add(object);
        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        params.put("SUBREPORT_DIR", reportSourcePath());
        params.put("LOGO",new FileInputStream(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRealPath("/resources/images/logo-ans-sem-slogan.png")));

        return gerarRelatorio(relatorio, beans, params, FORMATO_RELATORIO.PDF);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your data model, but maybe you have a cycle in the object model i.e. obj1 refers to obj2 that refers to obj1 again? A simple model mapping would cause infinite recursion which leads to a stack overflow. Maybe the object mapper for obj2 should use a mapper that only maps a subset of obj1 instead to avoid the recursion.

Comment: In this case the error would always happen, but it does not happen when the amount of data is small.

Comment: How would it always happen? This is inherently data dependent. Maybe your "small" data set does not have cycles? It could also be that you are just hitting the thread stack limit and the structure is actually legit. If so, try increasing the thread stack size with the `-Xss` setting e.g `-Xss1M`

Comment: My eclipse.ini file:  

-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms1024m
-Xmx2048m
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM


do I need to put -Xss1M?

Comment: I don't think that you application runs within the eclipse JVM so you probably need to adapt the run configuration of your application.